# how to find the url to connect SharePoint with C# console application

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

My C# console application is built on SharePoint Server 2007. My job is to select all items in the library from a SharePoint site. However, I cannot connect my app with a SharePoint site's SPSite object...

My code to connect SharePoint site:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace TryToConnect
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string siteurl = "http://sp13vm123/";
         //string siteurl = "http://sp13vm123/imgLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx";
         //string siteurl = "http://sp13vm123/imgLibrary/";
         //string siteurl = "http://sp13vm123:8800/";
         //string siteurl = "http://sp13vm123/SitePages/Home.aspx";
         //string siteurl = "http://sp13vm123/SitePages/";


            SPSite oSpSite = new SPSite(siteurl );
            Console.WriteLine("connected");//nothing
        }
    }
}
```

There is an error message about URL cannot found...

So, how can I find the URL to let me connect?

> The URL of SharePoint central Administration? error, not found
>
> The URL of Layout Page? error, not found

Comment: @rene so,what is the url that i can connect with in client mode?

Comment: @Rene As king mentioned "C# console application is built on the SharePoint server 2007.",Do you really think that he need to use CSOM

Comment: @king If your console application is on SharePoint server then you don't need to user CSOM but if you are doing it on remote server then you need to use csom

Comment: YA, i am confused that why i need to use client mode which i am the admin and the application is running on the server? It is not make sense.

Comment: @Akshay so, how can i connect the SharePoint library? many information on the internet is telling me to use SPSite to connect! However, i cannot find the url to connect wirh..

Comment: You just need to pass proper site url, this is the url of sharepoint site where you library exist.

Comment: Still not found, my URL is found in SharePoint central web Application Management..

Comment: Could you please share exact error message?

Comment: @Akshay The error message is about "The Web application at http://sp13vm123/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application." Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2007, you can only use `SPSite` objects (and any other objects from the SharePoint object model) when your code is executed from a web server on the SharePoint farm.

If you're running it from any other location, it will not have access to the SharePoint object model, and you'll need to use another approach (such as [SharePoint's SOAP-based web services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390(v=office.12).aspx)).

Comment: My project is running on SharePoint server, but it always said "The Web application at http://sp13vm123/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.". Therefore, i post this question that what is the correct URL to connect with..

Comment: But when you pull up a web browser on the server and navigate to `http://sp13vm123` it loads the SharePoint site correctly?

Comment: yes, it is. So i have no idea what is the problem.. will it have any permission problem?